# Html form Chrome browser setting strange value(WYŚLIJ) as input type(submit) value

Tags: html, forms, google-chrome, browser

myform:

```
 <input name="submit_active" id="submit_active" class="submit_active cancel_submit" type="submit" value="SUBMIT">
```

post data:

```
POST:<QueryDict: { u'submit_active': [u'WY\u015aLIJ'], u'agreeToTerms': [u'yes'], u'County': [u'West Midlands'],u'debitCardType': [u'VISA Delta']}>,
```

Browser:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0) AppleWebKit/536.5 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/19.0.1084.52 Safari/536.5
```

I don't know how the value of submit button changed to u'WY\u015aLIJ'.For Around 50 different user u'submit_active' the same value [u'WY\u015aLIJ'] is coming in post data.Is this related to any specific browser issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you supporting users who might have translated the page? "WYŚLIJ" means "SEND" in Polish (according to Google translate).

- Page is rendered translated
- Form is submitted by user
- Browser gathers values from form
- Hidden values (like "agreeToTerms") are not impacted
- Visible text has been translated
- Form is posted with translated text as the value in the name/value pair for submit button

Note that the name of the button will only be present in the request collection if it is the button that was clicked. The value of the button usually isn't that important when analyzing the request.

Comment: That's a great finding, but i do have a doubt on it.Users for my aplication are from UK only.  The agreeToTerms field isn't hidden field in my application and it's not impacted. Can there be any other reason?

Comment: To be clear, when I said "hidden value", I meant that it wasn't text that would be translated because the values submitted were coming from value text not display text (maybe). Regardless, the other possibility that comes to mind is that Chrome tries to convert the page into what it *thinks* is the correct language by displaying a "do you want to translate this page" message across the top of the page. If 1) the page has content which triggers this message and 2) some users blindly click it, then you could get this behavior.